# YouTube Live ffmpeg DVR

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using ffmpeg to stream to YouTube live.  I have everything working perfectly.

When I enable DVR on my channel I immediately start receiving playback errors on all iOS devices.  When I disable DVR I immediately fix the DVR issue.

I've tried changing the GOV and my KeyFrames.  YouTube live's control panel does not indicated any errors.

Anyone else seen this?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the ffmpeg log when DVR is enabled? YouTube might switch the HLS playlist type from `LIVE` to `EVENT`, so maybe it's a good idea to enable DVR *before* starting the stream.

Comment: No errors at all in the FFMPEG log.  We setup the stream originally with DVR on - it broke 4 hours later on iOS devices.  Now when we toggle it breaks immediately.  The 4 hour delay was what led me to believe it was keyframes - but I've set those now and it still breaks.

Comment: 4 hours is the DVR window @30 fps. Can you post the `ffmpeg` command please?

Comment: -rtsp_transport tcp -i {ipcameraurl} -b:v 3000k -vcodec libx264 -s 1920x1080  -acodec aac -b:a 128k -vol 5  -threads 2 -preset superfast   -vf \"movie=logo.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h, drawtext=fontfile=arial.ttf:text='%{localtime}':fontsize=18:fontcolor=white: box=1: boxcolor=black@.7  [out]\"  -f flv {rtmpurl};